The Label widget does not display the KivyMD text
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from socket import *
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class TestApp(MDApp):
   def build(self):
       self.label1 = MDLabel(font_style="H5", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
       Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label_text, 1)
       return self.label1

   def update_label_text(self, dt):
       client = socket(
           AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
       )
       client.connect(('192.168.5.99', 7000))
       data = client.recv(1024)
       msg = data.decode('utf-8')
       while True:
           data = client.recv(1024)
           msg = data.decode('utf-8')
           print(f'SERVER MSG:\n\t{msg}')
           self.label1.text = msg

TestApp().run()

The text is displayed in the console, but not in the Label.
My code is that the client reads the data from the server and displays it in the Label widget. This widget is also updated every second, because the server sends new data to the client every 10 seconds.
I expect the label to display my text.
